# realloc overlapping pointers with different one

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I'm trying to learn C and found a nice exercise that is giving me some problems. In particular i wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "trip.h"

struct accounting{
    char ** people;
    char ** descriptions;
    float * amountMoney;
    int * payers;
    int participants;
    int payments;
};

struct accounting *accountTable;

void trip_initialize(){
    accountTable = malloc(sizeof(struct accounting));
    accountTable->people = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    accountTable->descriptions = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    accountTable->amountMoney = malloc(sizeof(float *));

    accountTable->amountMoney = malloc(sizeof(float *));
    accountTable->payers = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    accountTable->participants = 0;
    accountTable->payments = 0;
};

void trip_shutdown(){

    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->participants; i++){
        free(accountTable->people[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->payments; i++){
        free(accountTable->descriptions[i]);
    }
    free(accountTable->amountMoney);
    free(accountTable->payers);
    free(accountTable->people);
    free(accountTable->descriptions);
    free(accountTable);
};

int trip_add_person(const char * name){
    accountTable->people = realloc(accountTable->people,sizeof(accountTable->people) + sizeof(char *));
    if (!accountTable->people){
        return -1;
    }
    accountTable->people[accountTable->participants] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    accountTable->people[accountTable->participants] = strdup(name);
    return accountTable->participants++;
};

int trip_find_person(const char * name){
    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->participants; i++){
        if (!strcmp(accountTable->people[i], name)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};

int trip_add_expense(const char * descr, float amount, int payer){
    if (payer < 0 || payer > accountTable->participants){
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->descriptions = realloc(accountTable->descriptions, sizeof(accountTable->descriptions) +  sizeof(char *));
    if (!accountTable->descriptions){
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->amountMoney = realloc(accountTable->amountMoney, sizeof(accountTable->amountMoney) + sizeof(float *));
    if (!accountTable->amountMoney){
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->payers = realloc(accountTable->payers, sizeof(accountTable->payers) + sizeof(int *));
    if (!accountTable->payers){
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->descriptions[accountTable->payments] = strdup(descr);
    accountTable->amountMoney[accountTable->payments] = amount;
    accountTable->payers[accountTable->payments] = payer;
    accountTable->payments++;
    return 1;
};
```

Now, I admit I have some problems understanding exactly how pointers and memory allocation work and I know there are probably more efficient ways to do this exercise.

My problem is that if I insert some persons into the system everything works fine, if I then insert 3 or more expenses the pointers of description from people[2] onward will point to the same memory positions of description. E.G. if I add 2 expenses everything is ok,if I then add one more the pointer of the newly added person will point to the memory location of description[0], the next person i insert will point to description[1] and so on overriding the names and if I add more people i will override the previously saved descriptions.

I really don't understand why this happens since from what i read realloc() won't go over other memory positions already used by another malloc.

If i print the pointers i will get

```
person pointer[0] 0x7ff73b404a20
person pointer[1] 0x7ff73b404a28
person pointer[2] 0x7ff73b404a30

description pointer[0] 0x7ff73b404a30
description pointer[1] 0x7ff73b404a38
description pointer[2] 0x7ff73b404a40
```

as you can see person[2] points to the same location as description[0] and if I continue person[3] will point to description[1] and so on.

I think I introduced some undefined behavior somewhere but I can't really understand where.

P.S. If you try to copy and paste this code trip_shutdown() won't work because free(accountTable->descriptions[0]) will try to free a pointer already freed in the previous loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Transcribed Comments

> Quotes are from [John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296075/john-smith).

Any line like: `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` is a memory leak waiting to happen. If the reallocation fails, you've just overwritten `oldptr` with `NULL`, so you can't free the still allocated memory. Always use:

```
newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);
if (newptr != 0) { oldptr = newptr; oldsize = newsize; }
else { …handle error… }
```

(if you're keeping track of sizes — or `oldcount = newcount;` if you're counting array entries).

> From what I understood `oldptr` gets overwritten by NULL and freeing a NULL doesn't do anything; that's why I check if it's NULL and return 0 if it is (the exercise explicitly stated to return 0 in this case). I thought that when `realloc` returns NULL the old pointer would've been freed automatically but apparently this isn't the case. I'll keep that in mind!

I think you're running into problems with your `realloc()` calls in `trip_add_expense()`. You're not taking into account the number of items already allocated — `sizeof(accountTable->descriptions)` does not do what you seem to think it does, for example. You should track the number of pointers in each array (or set of arrays) separately, and resize using that and the entry size, etc.

```
size_t new_size = accountTable->num_desc + 1;
char **new_desc = realloc(accountTable->descriptions, (new_size * sizeof(*accountTable->descriptions));
```

and error check, except growing by 1 is suboptimal too.

Calling `free(NULL)` does no harm (but no good either), but the memory that `oldptr` was pointing to was not freed by `realloc()` when it failed, but you can no longer pass that pointer to `free()` because it was overwritten.  That's the memory leak.  (It isn't the only leak in your code, either.)

> So, I do the `realloc` with `accountTable->description + sizeof(char *)` because I thought I needed an additional `char *` that I later use to store the pointer to the start of the description string. Is this wrong and I need to take into account the number of descriptions I have already stored? Also I know growing by 1 is suboptimal and it should be double the size like Python does for arrays (if I remember correctly) but since this, for me, was more an exercise on pointers I preferred to do it like this to write it faster.

One of the problems is that you are always allocating the same space; the size is fixed. Unless you're dealing with variable length arrays (which you're not), `sizeof(x)` is a compile-time constant.

> So, tell me if I understood correctly. No matter how many times I write `accountTable->description = realloc(accountTable->description + sizeof(char *))` the result will always be pretty much `sizeof(accountTable->description) + sizeof(char *)` because `sizeof` is a compile-time constant right? This would explain why it breaks with more than 2 entries; the first one is valid because I did the initial malloc and the second because I increase the size by `sizeof(char *)`.

Yes; that's basically correct. For the third entry, you're allocating as much space as you allocated for two entries, and for 4, 5, 6 entries you're allocating the same as for 2 entries. This is not going to lead to happiness if you try to use the extra entries that you thought you allocated but did not actually allocate. You could demonstrate by printing the size values you're passing to the allocation functions. How do you know how many people, descriptions, amounts and payers there are (how big each array is)?

#### Code

This is roughly what you need to do.  Note that I've annotated a few extra mistakes over and above those already mentioned in the commentary to the question.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct accounting
{
    char **people;
    char **descriptions;
    float *amountMoney;
    int *payers;
    int participants;
    int payments;
};

struct accounting *accountTable;

extern int trip_add_person(const char *name);
extern int trip_find_person(const char *name);
extern void trip_shutdown(void);
extern void trip_initialize(void);
extern int trip_add_expense(const char *descr, float amount, int payer);

void trip_initialize(void)
{
    accountTable = malloc(sizeof(struct accounting));
    assert(accountTable != 0);
    accountTable->people = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    accountTable->descriptions = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    /*accountTable->amountMoney = malloc(sizeof(float *)); // Repeated - leak! */
    accountTable->amountMoney = malloc(sizeof(float *));
    accountTable->payers = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    accountTable->participants = 0;
    accountTable->payments = 0;
    assert(accountTable->people != 0 && accountTable->descriptions != 0 &&
           accountTable->amountMoney != 0 && accountTable->payers != 0);
}

void trip_shutdown(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->participants; i++)
        free(accountTable->people[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->payments; i++)
        free(accountTable->descriptions[i]);
    free(accountTable->amountMoney);
    free(accountTable->payers);
    free(accountTable->people);
    free(accountTable->descriptions);
    free(accountTable);
}

int trip_add_person(const char *name)
{
    size_t new_num = accountTable->participants + 1;
    char **new_acct = realloc(accountTable->people, new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->people));
    if (new_acct == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->people));
        return -1;
    }
    accountTable->people = new_acct;
    /*accountTable->people[accountTable->participants] = malloc(sizeof(char *)); // Leak with strdup! */
    accountTable->people[accountTable->participants] = strdup(name);
    return accountTable->participants++;
}

int trip_find_person(const char *name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < accountTable->participants; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(accountTable->people[i], name))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int trip_add_expense(const char *descr, float amount, int payer)
{
    if (payer < 0 || payer > accountTable->participants)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    size_t new_num = accountTable->payments + 1;
    char **new_desc = realloc(accountTable->descriptions, new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->descriptions));
    if (new_desc == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->descriptions));
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->descriptions = new_desc;
    float *new_money = realloc(accountTable->amountMoney, new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->amountMoney));
    if (new_money == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->amountMoney));
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->amountMoney = new_money;
    int *new_payers = realloc(accountTable->payers, new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->payers));
    if (new_payers == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", new_num * sizeof(*accountTable->payers));
        return 0;
    }
    accountTable->payers = new_payers;
    accountTable->descriptions[accountTable->payments] = strdup(descr);
    accountTable->amountMoney[accountTable->payments] = amount;
    accountTable->payers[accountTable->payments] = payer;
    accountTable->payments++;
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    trip_initialize();
    int who_1 = trip_add_person("Original Poster");
    int who_2 = trip_add_person("Question Answerer");
    int who_3 = trip_add_person("Antibody");
    if (who_1 == -1 || who_2 == -1 || who_3 == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops - Adding people!\n");
    if (trip_add_expense("Deposit", 200.0, who_1) == 0 ||
        trip_add_expense("Deposit", 200.0, who_2) == 0 ||
        trip_add_expense("Deposit", 200.0, who_3) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops - adding expenses!\n");

    trip_shutdown();
}
```

It runs cleanly under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) and compiles cleanly using this command (source file name `mm31.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror mm31.c -o mm31
$
```

Note that the triple allocations for description, amount, payer is a mess.  You should have:

```
struct Payment
{
    char *description;
    float amount;
    int payer;
};
```

and your structure should contain a pointer to an array of those.  It would radically simplify the `trip_add_expense()` function.

I think you've always got one more space allocated than you're using in the arrays.  It is often best to leave the pointers unallocated until you first need some space.  Then I'd allocate something like `size_t new_num = (old_num + 2) * 2;` units and keep a record of how many units are allocated and how many are in use.  This allocates 4, then 12, then 28 … entries for use (a power of 2 minus 4, as it happens — the `+ 2` deals with `old_num == 0`; you can also use `new_num = old_num * 2 + 2`, giving you 2, 6, 14, 30, … as the sizes).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much I understood everything :) as i said, i know this isn't the easiest and more reasonable way to do it (in fact the provided solution to the exercise used two arrays of structures, one for the payments and the other for the people inserted)